# how to share my custom Activity methods to an ActionBarActivity without copy paste their implementation

Tags: android, methods, share, extends

I have a custom Activity with methods, and in my new project need to use an ActionBarActivity. 
I can't extend ActionBarActivity, so how can I use additionnal methods of my custom Activity without copy paste their implementation in the ActionBarActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare your methods as `public static` inside CustomActiviy, then all you'd have to do is call them on ActionBarActivity like:

```
CustomActiviy.method(params);
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution, compared to what I want! (Do not have to do too copy and paste, as I should with interfaces) But I leave the question open a little, to see if there is someone with a better solution, after a little time I'll validate your answer if there is no better

Answer (score 0):

extend your custom activity to ActionBarActivity
and extend your normal activity to CustomActivity :)

Comment: you can use interfaces

Comment: the idea is not bad, but I prefer to avoid using default objects library support, sometimes bug unlike the original version, or does not behave exactly the same way